# How child div width can be made auto when parent div width is fixed

Tags: html, css

```
<ul class='navbar-nav '>
          <li  class='profile'>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="profile-pet-block">
              <li class="profile-pet-block">
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

    .navbar-nav {
      width: 115px;
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
      padding: 20px 0px;
    }

    li.profile {
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 25px
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
      width: 234px;
      top: -23%;
      left: 114px;
      height: 88px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      position:absolute
    } 

    .profile-pet-block {
      float: left;
      padding: 10px 10px!important;
      width: auto!important;
    }
```

I want Ul.dropdown-menu width to be auto as number of li inside ul is dynamic.How can i do that. Below is the screenshot attached of the ui

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfgcM.png

Comment: You need to provide more information. Please give a picture or video of the UI you are trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

adding `inline-block` to `ul.dropdown` will take the `width` of its children

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parent > ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.parent {
  width: 115px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.parent > ul >li {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.parent ul li ul.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li class="profile">
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried with inline-block but ul is not taking. If i fixed the width everything is working fine but i can't do that. i want ul.dropdown width to be auto.